# Performance with IN clause

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mysql-5.5, performance, query-performance

Does indexed data affect query performance? means If I passed value as 1,2,3,4... in ordered form in any `IN` clause, can it improve query performance? and what happen in case I pass value randomly 2,5,7,9,1 etc...

Example :

```
Select Name from Emp 
where id IN (1,2,3,4)  -- Ordered values
```

or:

```
Select Name from Emp 
where id IN (4,2,7,98,34) -- Randomly ordered values
```

Another way :

```
Select Name from Emp 
where id IN (Select empid from trans order by empty) -- Ordered values
```

I am asking for MySql as well as SQL-Server database.

And can any one tell me how database engine get result in above case (execution plan)?

Comment: Did ***you*** look at the execution plans? Did ***you*** see any difference? Also, in SQL Server, you should consider table-valued parameters instead of big `IN` lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first two queries, on SQL Server, the query optimizer will order the values for you before going to the database. You can confirm this by looking at the seek predicate for the execution plan of each of those queries. The execution plan for both queries is identical:

[image]

For the third query, as @gbn said, it will execute as a join. On my system it executes as an **inner join**. In this case, performance comes down to indexing and the number of records you are dealing with.

Answer (score 5):

They are 2 different concepts

- `where id IN ( 1,2,3,4)` is simply shorthand for `id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR ...`
- `where id IN (Select empid from trans order by empty)` is a **semi-join**

So, the ordering of values for the simple list of numbers makes no difference at all

For the semi-join, there should be an index anyway because it is a type of JOIN. Note that the ORDER BY inside the subquery would give an error on SQL Server because it makes no sense (unless you use TOP). Not sure about MySQL but I suspect it will simply ignore it.

Comment: thanks @gbn, But how engine goes to each pointer. means I have doubt, If I have pass values as 4,3,19,25,2 then engine first go to record no 4 then jump reverse on record 3 and then jump over 19 and 25 and again reverse on record no 2? so, I think this is not good.